# Why is {typedef int* PTR;const PTR p=&num;} not equivalent to "const int* p=&num" but to "int *const p=&num"?

Tags: c, pointers, constants, typedef

This thing was partly touched upon in another question on SO, but somewhat casually as it was not the main question. As my confusion still persists, I am putting it in a separate question.

Why are the following two statements equivalent to `int* const p=&num` and not `const int* p=&num` when the latter seems more logical and intuitive? What are the rigorous reasons for this behavior of `typedef`?

```
typedef int* PTR;
const PTR p=&num;
```

And finally, in that question one member remarks that it is bad practice to use `typedef`ed pointers. But I have seen it being widely used in many books and websites and it seems a convenient thing to do. It makes the code more understandable. So what is the final word on it? Should one avoid `typedef`ed pointers as much as possible?

**Edit:** And what will be the correct syntax for that `typedef` statement if we intend the following:

```
  const int* const p=&num;
```

**Edit:** I inadvertently forgot to ask an important thing. What is the correct syntax using that `typedef` statement for the following then?

```
  const int* p=&num;      //instead of the int* const p=&num that we got
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally,

```
const TYPE var = ini;
```

declares a `const` variable `var` of type `TYPE`. So

```
const PTR p=&num;
```

declares a `const` variable `p` of type `PTR`, initialised with the address of `num`.

A `typedef` is not a textual alias, so you can't just replace the `typedef`ed name with its expansion to see what it results in.

If you want to get

```
const int* const p=&num;
```

with a `typedef`, you must `typedef` something including `const int`, e.g.

```
typedef const int *CI_ptr;
```

and then you can write

```
const CI_ptr p = &num;
```

(but don't, it's ugly).

And for

```
const int *p = &num;
```

you can then write

```
CI_ptr p = &num;
```

> And finally,in that question one member remarks that it is bad practice to use `typedef`ed pointers.But I have seen it being widely used in many books and websites and seems a convenient thing to do,that makes the code more understandable.

Whether it makes the code more understandable or less depends. One thing that in my experience is always a bad thing is to `typedef` pointer types to names that hide the fact that you are dealing with pointers.

```
typedef struct list_node {
    int value;
    struct list_node next;
} *node;
```

for example is one unfortunately common abuse. When you read the type `node`, you don't suspect it's a pointer. At least typedef it to `node_ptr`. But then, why `typedef` the pointer at all, `typedef`ing the structure and using `node*` is shorter and clearer.

> So what is the final word on it? Should one avoid `typedef`ed pointers as much as possible?

There's no ultimate authority on it, so it's mostly your decision. Follow the coding style in the company/project if there is one, use your judgment if you're coding on your own.

Comment: I forgot to add 2 important points.I have added them as **Edits**.Can you kindly look into those?

Comment: One reason to have typedefs of pointer types is when you are using them as opaque objects outside an API.  So `struct foo_magic_structure; typdef my_magic_structure* foo_handle;` and then your API refers to `foo_handle` everywhere.  Of course, this applies much more to C than C++.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the issues of using `typedef` for object pointer types.

A qualifier (`const`, `volatile`) never penetrates a `typedef`.

That's one of the reasons some coding standards forbid the use of `typedef` for object pointer types.

Comment: Can you kindly look into my **Edit**,which I added just now to my question.